# how to build a covering space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I just started to learn for an exam but I am stuck in this exercise:
Let Y be a topological space with $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}/_{19}$ . Is there a covering space (order 4) ?
How do you construct a covering space in this case?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're given information about the fundamental group of $Y$, and want to get information about the covering spaces of $Y$. You should review what you've learned about the relationship between fundamental groups and covering spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: A connected covering space of $Y$ of order $4$ would correspond to a subgroup of $\pi_1(Y)$ of index $4$.

If you don't require connectedness then it is easy to find a covering space of any order.

Comment: @kobloau: Do you know about Lagrange's theorem in finite group theory?